# Visual studio 2008 release build : application crashes on basic string or basic pointer operations

Tags: c++

I have a application compiled in Visual studio 2008,which runs fine in debug build. In release build , the application crashes when std::wstring assignment is done or when shared pointer is accessed. Any idea why this happens in release build.
crash at : 
eg: m_name = name; //m_name and name are of type std::wstring

Comment: can you post the code for the class as well as how you are using it? looks like you are trying to use an unitialized memory location.

Comment: How did you find out the location of crash in release build? Did you build it with PDB? If yes, then you can anyways find out the reason for crash in release build.

Answer (score 1):

In debug mode, some compilers will set values of pointers to default values (like null) for example. But in release mode the value of the pointer will be whatever is on the stack at that location and will be pointing to an invalid object thus resulting in a crash.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably a memory corruption caused by some other part of your program. Double check that your bounds checks are correct everywhere, you can also use specialized tools like Memory Validator or Bounds Checker.